# Sublattices , lattice of subgroups of a group is complete?

Tags: lattice-orders

It is asked to show that sublattices of a lattice form a complete lattice under subset relation( I am not sure if the symbol is of just a relation R) and also to show that the lattice of subgroups of a group is complete. 
First of all I have a doubt about my question that is it asked to find under any relation R or it is subset relation. Then I need a systematic way to show this. I know the definitions. And what if show the one asked in next question by an example?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A lattice is complete if and only if it is closed under arbitrary meets. What is the meet for subgroups or sublattices?

If you find a familiar description of these meets, it is easy to conclude.